# Does AWS recycle unused global namespaces (such as S3) or are they not only unique but permanent?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know namespaces for S3 have to be globally unique but I have seen nothing on if AWS has a process for recycling unused namespaces which makes me wonder if they are unique in perpetuity.

Comment: Never actually tested this, but from their documentation (Bucket names must be unique across all existing bucket names in Amazon S3.) it sounds to me like it only applies to existing names. If it doesn't exist, you can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're calling namespaces are S3 bucket names. They're globally unique. If you own an S3 bucket and you delete it, another AWS account can later create an S3 bucket with the name that you previously used.

A small experiment suggests:

- the bucket name is immediately available for reuse by the same account
- the bucket name is *not* immediately available for reuse by other accounts but once AWS has cleared up everything it needs to then it becomes available (in my test that process took 30+ minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a Bucket name like a domain name. For example if you were to create a bucket with any name that you want that is available then it will be created, if you were to delete that bucket you could then immediately turn around and create that bucket with the same name.